# PHP date/due date

Tags: php

I'm asking for an algo/idea to solve my problem. This is the scenario:

- due date is Nov 21, 2011
- current date is Nov 18, 2011
- 3 days before the due date, I want an image to appear on the div [days is dynamic]

So meaning on nov 18, 2011 the div as an image already, the following day nov 19, 2011 the div has also image and same scenario on nov 20, 2011. But on Nov 17, 2011 there is no image on the div

how can I do it with PHP? Don't mind the image on the div. I'll handle that. Just only the condition on the dates.

anyone who can give me algo/idea? only algo/idea..
Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Hi. StackOverflow is not a code request site. Use rentacoder.com for that. If you want help here, please show us what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: I'm not asking for the code. Just an idea on how to do it.

Comment: I was going to post complete code, but no. You are too lazy to type "date difference php" in google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your date to a UNIX timestamp using [mktime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) or [strtotime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and then do the following:

```
$date_diff = 60*60*24*3; // 3 days
// time()+$date_diff will be a timestamp 3 days in the future
if ($due_date < time()+$date_diff) {
    echo "less than 3 days left!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

visit http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php !

Example #1 time() example

```
<?php
$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
                   // 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60secs
echo 'Now:       '. date('Y-m-d') ."\n";
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', $nextWeek) ."\n";
// or using strtotime():
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week')) ."\n";
?>
```

:))